# CSS Can a background image fill its parent div to the left instead of right?

Tags: html, css, dom, web

This isn't possible that I know of, but it would be incredibly useful if one of you fine folks has a solution for me.  So, if an image does not have enough room to completely display, the right side of the image is cut off.  Is it possible to have it instead cut off the left side of the image?  My ultimate goal would be as the window size increases, the image fills in on the left side rather than on the right.

Answer (score 4):

The `background-position` property used in conjunction with `background-size` is probably what you are looking for:

`background-position: right center;
 background-size: contain;`

More information can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Comment: This resizes the image to a smaller width and height, I wanted to keep the height and have the rest of the width appear that was previously hidden off screen or otherwise hidden.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kkf8u8u7/

I think this is what you are after, if you don't want the use background image

```
div {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}
img {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
#left {
  left:0px;
}
#right {
  right:0px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for exactly what I want.  I'm trying to have it stay the same height and as the resolution of the window changes, only the left side of the image appears, the right stays exactly where it was. Thanks for your reply.